# how to rename a file in removeable sdcard in android 5

Tags: android, permissions, rename, sd-card, android-external-storage

I unable to rename file in removeable SDCard in android 5.
I trying rename with this code:

`File oldfile = new File(old);
File newfile = new File(new);
oldfile.renameTo(newfile);`

this code working in device storage fine. but in removeable sdcard not work.
this problem there is in android 5 and above.I know for Android 5 I have to use SAF and for Android over runtime permissions. But I do not know how to do this for rename.
please help me.
Thanks

Comment: What does "problem" mean? Do you get an exception? Does it just silently execute?

Comment: The file name can not be renamed in the SD card. Error message does not occur. @Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I leave it for those who don't know

```js
final static String PREF_DEFAULT_URI = "pref_default_uri";
 String strUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         
strUri = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(PREF_DEFAULT_URI, null);
 
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strUri)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            } else {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(strUri);
                DocumentFile rootDocumentfile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
                updateViews(rootDocumentfile);
            }
    
    Button rename = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rename);
    rename.setOnClickListener(this);
}

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString(PREF_DEFAULT_URI, uri.toString()).commit();
            DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
            updateViews(documentFile)
        }
    }

public void renameclick(View v) {
    File oldfile = new File(old);
    File newfile = new File(new);

    DocumentFile fileuri = getDocumentFilePath(getApplicationContext(),oldfile.getAbsolutePath(),strUri);
 fileuri.renameTo(newfile.getName());
}


public static DocumentFile getDocumentFilePath(Context context, String path,String sdCardUri) {
  DocumentFile document = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, Uri.parse(sdCardUri));
  String[] parts = path.split("/");
  for (int i = 3; i < parts.length; i++) {
   document= document.findFile(parts[i]);
  }
  return document;
}
                                         
public void updateViews(DocumentFile document) {
    /////////
    /////////
}
```